# Choosing launcher programatically without selecting from dialog box

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities
a) LauncherMainActivity
b) FakeHome

The problem is that when I run the application and press the home button a dialog box opens up showing list of launchers.
I don't want any dialog box to open, just want to make the LaunherMainActivity implicitly as default home.
Also when user exit this application on button click, the previous launcher or default launcher should be made default home.

I have added the following lines to the manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.launcherm.LauncherMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.launcherm.FakeHome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fake_home" 
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The code for the button by which the default launcher is made home is given below. The main problem in this code is that it shows a dialog box to the user. But i want default home should be made implicitly on button click.

```
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
           ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(LauncherMainActivity.this, FakeHome.class);
           p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

           Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

           selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);            
            startActivity(selector);

           p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
       }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want any dialog box to open, just want to make the LaunherMainActivity implicitly as default home

Fortunately, that is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, for obvious security reasons. You cannot hijack the user's HOME button. The user is welcome to make your your app be the default home screen via the dialog.

Comment: I have downloaded the application called MagicLocker from google play store and run it on Android 4.4.4 OS. They have done the same thing which i want.